# Problems Displaying a PHP Array Value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm pulling a JSON file for various games from Steam so I can make a vote-able list. The end goal involves pulling info like Name, Logo, and some of the VR info from this and inputting it into a MySQL database. At the moment, though, I'm having trouble displaying only the name value from this array.

I simply don't understand PHP Arrays as much as I need to. I haven't been able to find what I need from googling or on here, so I apologize if this is considered a duplicate.

I was hoping I could get some example code to display the "Name" field who's result in this is Windlands in this example. I should hopefully be able to figure it out from there.

```
$appID = "428370";
$api = "https://steampics-mckay.rhcloud.com/info?apps=".$appID."&prettyprint=1";

$json = file_get_contents($api);
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$jsonArray = iterator_to_array ($jsonIterator, true);

echo $jasonArray["apps"][428370]["common"]["name"];
```

The original JSON file can be found here: 
https://steampics-mckay.rhcloud.com/info?apps=428370&prettyprint=1

Using some code I found on this site earlier, I was able to get this result:

```
[0]=> string(4) "apps" 
[1]=> int(428370) 
[2]=> string(6) "common" 
[3]=> string(4) "name"
```

So I'm not sure what I've been doing wrong.

Thank you in advance for the help. :)

Comment: what about just `json_decode($json, true);` instead of all this iterator thing? and you can peek your resulting array with `print_r()` or `var_dump()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$appID = "428370";
$api = "https://steampics-mckay.rhcloud.com/info?apps=".$appID."&prettyprint=1";

$json = file_get_contents($api);
$jasonArray = json_decode($json, true);

echo $jasonArray["apps"][428370]["common"]["name"];
```